# Staying open with DI/IoC containers

Tags: ioc-container

I am involved with several open source projects which taken together provide an application development framework. The question I have is what mechanism(s) should I provide for integrating them with each other?

On the conceptual level the answer is clear - DI/IoC. The "only" problem is to decide which one. In several installations we used StructureMap, but then a user came along who wanted only one of the components and wanted NInject.

So, to qualify the question, how should I go about building my components so that they can be integrated with each other (and 3rd Party) using a variety of DI/IoC containers.

The best I could come up with was to separate out all integration code into separate projects and then have a project per supported IoC container, but this sounds suspiciously like IoC squared.

Any bright ideas? or I am just thinking too hard?

P.S. for the curious: [NDjango](http://bit.ly/3iHB8D); [Bistro](http://bit.ly/a2rVZk); [Workflow Server](http://bit.ly/b1QgPs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you develop reusable components, you can implement them in a [DI-friendly way without ever referencing any particular DI Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library/2047657#2047657).

It' only when you need to compose an actual, running application that you need the DI Container, but as I understand, you are developing a framework, and it's best to keep it DI-neutral.

Answer (score 2):

See [this very related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library) (almost a duplicate).

For inspiration about integrating several projects while keeping them independent, see the [Castle Project](http://castleproject.org/).