# Is it possible to create a Func that takes T as runtime parameter?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, func

Is it possible to create a `Func` that has a generic `T` as runtime parameter?

I'm using `Func` to create some instances that are using generics. I would like to do something like this:

```
var myFunc = new Func<IEnumerable<T>>(x => new List<T>());
IEnumerable<string> result = myFunc<string>();
IEnumerable<int> result2 = myFunc<int>();
IEnumerable<Bar> result3 = myFunc<Bar>();
```

But it obviously doesn't compile because `T` is unknown at this moment. The code below will compile, but it will not work in my case since I need the strongly typed `List<T>`.

```
var func = new Func<IList>(() => new ArrayList());
```

If it's not possible with `Func`, is it possible with `Expression` or `delegates`?

For background info I can say that I'm using this as part of a factory pattern together with Unity IoC. I'm building on this example: [Unity auto-factory with params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825270/unity-auto-factory-with-params).

**EDIT:**
I realise that my question was poorly asked. Sorry for that. I tried to keep the question simple by not including the background (purpose). The whole point is that I'm using Unity as IoC and have a factory that looks like this:

```
public interface ICollectionWrapperFactory
{
    ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> items);
}

public class CollectionWrapperFactory :ICollectionWrapperFactory
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;

    public CollectionWrapperFactory(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        ICollectionWrapper<T> collectionWrapper;
        if (items == null)
        {
            collectionWrapper = _container.Resolve<ICollectionWrapper<T>>(new ParameterOverride("items", new T[0]));
        }
        else
        {
            collectionWrapper = _container.Resolve<ICollectionWrapper<T>>(new ParameterOverride("items", items));
        }
        return collectionWrapper;
    }
}
```

It is using the `IUnityContainer` to resolve the instance. But I want to remove the dependency to `IUnityContainer` from the implementation because of the service locator anti-pattern. Instead I want to do something like this:

```
public class CollectionWrapperFactory :ICollectionWrapperFactory
{
    private readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>, ICollectionWrapper<T>> _createFunc;

    public CollectionWrapperFactory(Func<IEnumerable<T>, ICollectionWrapper<T>> createFunc)
    {
        _createFunc = createFunc;
    }

    public ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        ICollectionWrapper<T> collectionWrapper;
        if (items == null)
        {
            collectionWrapper = _createFunc(new T[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            collectionWrapper = _createFunc(items);
        }
        return collectionWrapper;
    }
}

public class CollectionWrapper<TModel> : ICollectionWrapper<TModel>
{
    private IEnumerable<TModel> _items;

    public CollectionWrapper(IEnumerable<TModel> items)
    {
        _items = items;
        TotalCount = items.Count();
    }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<TModel> Items
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set { _items = value; }
    }
}
```

And in my registration:

```
   container.RegisterType<ICollectionWrapperFactory, CollectionWrapperFactory>(
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
        new InjectionConstructor(
            new Func<IEnumerable<T>, ICollectionWrapper<T>>(
                items => container.Resolve<ICollectionWrapper<T>>(new ParameterOverride("items", items)))));

container.RegisterType(typeof(ICollectionWrapper<>), typeof(CollectionWrapper<>), new TransientLifetimeManager());
```

This way I will remove the dependency to IUnityContainer from the implementation and thus the service locator anti-pattern (I guess?). Instead I need to inject the func to create the instance, but I don't know how to inject a func with a generic parameter.

Good examples for exactly what I want, but with generics:

[Factory pattern without service locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023161/factory-pattern-without-service-locator)

[Unity auto-factory with params](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825270/unity-auto-factory-with-params)

Comment: The actual question is: what should your `result` be if `T` is NOT of tyüpe `string`, but of type `int` for instance? How should this be converted to an `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: Using a good old method would be a problem?

Comment: @codroipo > Yes, it may suffice as long as I can inject it with Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap that in method.

```
public static class MyFactories {
    public static Func<IEnumerable<T>> CreateListFactory<T>() {
        return () => new List<T>();
    }
}
// ... somewhere else
var myFunc = MyFactories.CreateListFactory<string>();
var result = myFunc(); // it will be List<string>
```

**EDIT:**
If you want declare generic fields/properties, you must specify the generic parameter in class.

```
public class CollectionWrapperFactory<T> : ICollectionWrapperFactory
{
    private readonly Func<IEnumerable<T>, ICollectionWrapper<T>> _createFunc;

    public CollectionWrapperFactory(Func<IEnumerable<T>, ICollectionWrapper<T>> createFunc)
    {
        _createFunc = createFunc;
    }

    public ICollectionWrapper<T> CreateCollection(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        ICollectionWrapper<T> collectionWrapper;
        if (items == null)
        {
            collectionWrapper = _createFunc(new T[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            collectionWrapper = _createFunc(items);
        }
        return collectionWrapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've updated my question with a little more information regarding the problem. Do you think that it's still possible to do it this way? I need to be able to inject the method.

Comment: I believe you're right. But I really wanted to avoid this since the factory is used on a lot of places and I would like to keep the class itself non-generic, but with generic methods. Thanks for clearing it out for me.

Comment: It's small class. The unity performance overhead is bigger than instantiation of this class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple method as a factory.

```
Func<IEnumerable<T>> CreateFunc<T>() {
    return () => new List<T>();
}

// Usage
var func = CreateFunc<string>();
var list = func();
```