# How to make Ninject choose a specific constructor without using InjectAttribute?

Tags: ninject

1) Is there a way to make Ninject select a specific constructor in code other than applying the `InjectAttribute`?

2) Also, how do I supply values for these arguments of the constructor?

3) Can I override these argument values on resolution or creation of the object, i.e. when I call `kernel.Get<T>()`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12683042/684096

Answer (score 1):

There's the `ToConstructor` binding method:

```
Bind<IMyService>().ToConstructor(
    ctorArg => new MyService(ctorArg.Inject<IFoo>()));
```

You can specify values on binding using 3 mechanisms:

- create a binding for the dependency (`Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>()`)
- specify a constructor argument (add a `WithConstructorArgument(typeof(IFoo), new Foo())` to the end of the binding)
- if i remember correctly, you can also specify it in the `ToConstructor` syntax like `ToConstructor(ctorArg => new MyService(myFoo));`

(Also see http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/05/28/ninject-constructor-selection-preview/)

You can specify values on resolution by passing a [`ConstructorArgument`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Parameters/ConstructorArgument.cs) or, preferrably, a [`TypeMatchingConstructorArgument`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Parameters/TypeMatchingConstructorArgument.cs) (or some custom [`IParameter`](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/blob/master/src/Ninject/Parameters/IParameter.cs)) to the resolution:

```
IResolutionRoot.Get<IMyService>(new TypedConstructorArgument(
    typeof(IFoo),
    (ctx, target) => myFooInstance));
```