# Configuring IoC container from modules/plug-ins?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container, mef, modularity

i am in big dilema..
I am working on highly modular web app in ASP.NET MVC 2 (in fact, core will be super lightweight, all work on modules/plugins). I found MEF pretty useful for modules discovery, but i dont want to us it as IoC container. There is pretty good chance that I will need advanced features of "true" IoC container, so I would like to use Unity.

And here is the problem : how to allow modules to configure container (programatically) = register their own types (mvc controllers, custom implementations of services...) at application start without making hard dependency on Unity in all modules ?
I know about Common Service Locator project, and it seems pretty good, but this interface co container only allows resolving types, not registering them (afaik).

I really hope you can understand my point, I know my english is terrible (I am from non english speaking country :)
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can certainly sympathize with not wanting to use MEF as a DI Container, but I think you should still consider whether that might not be applicable for your add-ins.

You **already require your add-ins to use MEF**, so they will all have a hard dependency on it. While I personally don't like the hard-coded, attribute-based approach used by MEF, it sounds like you are asking how each add-in can register itself with the DI Container. That also sounds like hard-coding to me, so you might as well just use MEF all the way in.

Applying MEF attributes *is* component registration.

If you really don't want to use MEF you only have a few other options (none of them particularly more attractive):

- Require all add-ins to also take a hard dependency on Unity. I completely understand why you don't want to do this, but I'm just including this option for the sake of completeness
- Require all add-ins to also take a hard dependency on Common Service Locator. In my view, this only shifts the problem slightly.
- **Define your own add-in registration interface** that all add-ins must implement. You can then write your own implementation that uses Unity, so that all add-ins register themselves against this interface, but then you would more or less just be duplicating the features of MEF.
- Write all add-ins in a [DI-friendly, but container-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library/2047657#2047657) style. This leaves the problem with configuring the DI Container, and you will then have to resort to XML configuration for that. This is a very **brittle** approach and can quickly lead to **maintainance hell**, so once again I'm just including this option for the sake of completeness.

Using MEF for add-ins doesn't preclude you from using Unity in your core application, but I do understand that it's very lightweight, so that may not make a lot of sense.

Comment: One open-source example of a plugin architecture that uses a custom registration interface like you mentioned is [NopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx). It uses Autofac, but the concepts are the same.