# inject different implementations by logged User Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

```
public class TheController : Controller
{
   IThe the;
   public TheController( IThe the)
   {
      //when User.IsInRole("r1") The1 should be injected else r2
      this.the = the;
   }
}

public class The1 : IThe{}
public class The2 : IThe{}

//anybody knows a good way of doing this ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IHandlerSelector` is the way to go. See [this post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/05/windsor-ihandlerselector.aspx) for an example of usage.

Alternatively if you prefer AutoFac-like experience you can use factory for that:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IThe>().UsingFactoryMethod(
  c => HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("r1") ?
    c.Resolve<IThe>("r1") :
    c.Resolve<IThe>("r2"));
```

Or if you want to use specific `IThe` just in one context, you can use DynamicParameters:

```
container.Register(Component.For<TheFactory>().Lifestyle.Transient.DynamicParameters(
  (c, d) => HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("r1") ?
    d["the"] = c.Resolve<IThe>("r1") :
    c.Resolve<IThe>("r2"));
```

However the most *correct* way of doing this is `IHandlerSelector`

Answer (score 1):

In Autofac:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Give the different implementations names
builder.RegisterType<The1>.Named<IThe>("r1");
builder.RegisterType<The2>.Named<IThe>("r2");

// Use a function for the default IThe
builder.Register(
  c => HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("r1") ?
    c.Resolve<IThe>("r1") :
    c.Resolve<IThe>("r2"))
  .As<IThe>()
  .ExternallyOwned();
```

If you have a lot of roles, you can use a method instead of the inline expression, e.g.:

```
builder.Register(c => ChooseTheImplementation(c))
```

(BTW, The "ExternallyOwned" modifier tells the container that the result of the function is disposed elsewhere, e.g. via the concrete components. You can usually leave it out but it makes good documentation :))

Comment: As far as I understand this answer, you would perform this registration in the application root. At that point, `User` isn't available (it's a property on the Controller class).

Comment: Fixed - now uses HttpContext. Thanks Mark.

Comment: is Windsor Castle capable of doing this kind of stuff ?

Comment: Yes- see Krzysztof's answer above. Windsor tends to favour interfaces over lambdas for it's extensibility points, but the net result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The [container-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library/2047657#2047657) approach obviously employs an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern):

```
public interface ITheFactory
{
    IThe Create(IPrincipal user);
}
```

You can take a dependency on ITheFactory instead of IThe:

```
public class TheController : Controller   
{   
    private readonly IThe the;   

    public TheController(ITheFactory theFactory)   
    {   
        if (theFactory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("theFactory");
        }

        this.the = theFactory.Create(this.User);
    }   
}
```

I can't really remember if `this.User` is populated at this time, but if it isn't, you can just keep a reference to the factory and lazily resolve your dependency the first time it's requested.

However, `Controller.User` is a bit special because it ought to be available as `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` as well. This means that *in this special case* you don't actually have to introduce an Abstract Factory. Instead, you can write a [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that performs the selection every time it's used:

```
public class UserSelectingThe : IThe
{
    private readonly IThe the1;
    private readonly IThe the2;

    public UserSelectingThe(IThe the1, IThe the2)
    {
        if (the1 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("the1");
        }
        if (the2 == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("the2");
        }

        this.the1 = the1;
        this.the2 = the2;
    }

    // Assuming IThe defines the Foo method:
    public Baz Foo(string bar)
    {
        if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole("r1"))
        {
            return this.the1.Foo(bar);
        }

        return this.the2.Foo(bar);
    }
}
```

In this case, you would be able to use your original TheController class unchanged.