# Can I have conditional construction of classes when using IoC.Resolve?

Tags: constructor, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, overloading

I have a service class which has overloaded constructors. One constructor has 5 parameters and the other has 4.

Before I call,

```
var service = IoC.Resolve<IService>();
```

I want to do a test and based on the result of this test, resolve service using a specific constructor. In other words,

```
        bool testPassed = CheckCertainConditions();
        if (testPassed)
        {
            //Resolve service using 5 paramater constructor
        }
        else
        {
            //Resolve service using 4 parameter constructor
            //If I use 5 parameter constructor under these conditions I will have epic fail.
        }
```

Is there a way I can specify which one I want to use?

Comment: It is possible with `DynamicParameters` but before you go try to use it - why do you need it in the first place? It sounds like a design flaw in your code more than anything else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My underlying problem was that I was trying to resolve my class which had the following signature:

```
public DatabaseSchemaSynchronisationService(IDatabaseService databaseService, IUserSessionManager userSessionManager)
```

This was basically useless to me because my usersessionmanager had no active NHibernate.ISession because a connection to my database had not yet been made. What I was trying to do was check if I did have a connection and only then resolve this class which served as a service to run database update scripts.

When changing my whole class to perform the scripts in a different way, all I needed in its constructor's signature was:

```
public DatabaseSchemaSynchronisationService(ISessionFactory sessionFactory)
```

This allowed me to open my own session. I did, however have to first check if the connection was ready before attempting to resolve the class, but having IDatabaseSchemaSynchronisationService as a parameter to another class's constructor; this class also gettting resolved somewhere where I could not check the db connection was a bad idea.

Instead in this second class, I took the IDatabaseSchemaSynchronisationService paramater out of the constructor signature and made it a local variable which only gets instantiated (resolved) :

```
if (connectionIsReady)
```

Thanks to everyone who answered.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should **watch out for ambiguity** in constructors when it comes to DI because you are essentially saying to any caller that *'I don't really care if you use one or the other'*. This is unlikely to be what you intended.

However, one [container-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library/2047657#2047657) solution is to wrap the conditional implementation into another class that implements the same interface:

```
public class ConditionalService : IService
{
    private readonly IService service;

    public ConditionalService()
    {
        bool testPassed = CheckCertainConditions();      
        if (testPassed)      
        {      
            // assign this.service using 5 paramater constructor      
        }      
        else      
        {      
            // assign this.service using 4 parameter constructor
        }  
    }

    // assuming that IService has a Foo method:
    public IBaz Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        return this.service.Foo(bar);
    }
}
```

If you can't perform the `CheckCertainConditions` check in the constructor, you can use **lazy evaluation** instead.

It would be a good idea to let ConditionalService request all dependencies via **Constructor Injection**, but I left that out of the example code.

You can register ConditionalService with the DI Container instead of the real implementation.