# How to use Autofac in a class library project?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

I have the following implementation:

```
private INewsRepository newsRepository;

public NewsService(INewsRepository newsRepository)
{
     this.newsRepository = newsRepository;
}
```

This service is in a separate project than that of my web project.  Where and how would I specify the dependency injection?  Would I still need to put it in my global.asax file?  What if this service is used my other apps as well?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should only reference the container from the root of the application (global.asax). This is known as the [Register Resolve Release pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx).

Your correct use of **Constructor Injection** ensures that you can reuse the NewsService class from other applications **without requiring that those other applications use a particular DI Container** (or any at all).

This is a good start at [designing the service in a DI Friendly manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library/2047657#2047657), yet keeping it **container agnostic**.

Answer (score 4):

```
[TestClass]
public class LogTest 
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Test project: autofac impl.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly ContainerBuilder _builder; 
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LogTest" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public LogTest()
    {
        //
        // Read autofac setup from the project we are testing
        //
        _builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        Register.RegisterTypes(_builder);
        _container = _builder.Build();

        loggingService = _container.Resolve<ILoggingService>(new NamedParameter("theType", this));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void DebugMsgNoExectption()
    {
        var a = _container.Resolve<IHurraService>();
        var b = a.ItsMyBirthday();

public class HurraService : IHurraService
{
    private IHurraClass _hurra;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HurraService" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public HurraService(IHurraClass hurra)
    {
        _hurra = hurra;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// It my birthday.
    /// </summary>
    public string ItsMyBirthday()
    {
        return _hurra.Hurra();
    }
}

public static class Register
{
    public static void RegisterTypes(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<LoggingService>().As<ILoggingService>();
        builder.RegisterType<HurraService>().As<IHurraService>();
        builder.RegisterType<HurraClass>().As<IHurraClass>();
    }
}
```

Inside the Class Library I created the "Register" class. Here the Autofac setup is done.
In my test project I read this file (Register.RegisterTypes) and init the _container.

Now I have access to Resolve all the goodies inside the project I am testing.

Comment: Where do you call Register?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it would depend on whether you intend to use the same assembly in multiple host applications. Does the assembly really require references to AutoFac? I would recommend against this, as if your requirements change later you would have a load of unnecessary references. Your host application should control how to assemble the modular parts, so I would leave configuration up to your host (in this case your web application. If you want to push some control of registration, you could create a type which handles the registration for you, but as I mentioned before, your assembly is essentially bound to using AutoFac e.g.:

```
public static class NewsRegistration()
{
    public static void RegisterTypes(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Register your specific types here.
        builder.RegisterType<NewsService>().As<INewsService>();
    }
}
```

That way you could easily call:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// Register common types here?

NewsRegistration.RegisterTypes(builder);

var container = builder.Build();
```