# Dependecy Injection Library Agnostic Code using a Common Wrapper class?

Tags: dependency-injection, wrapper

***Is anyone aware of a set of classes to abstract away the specific Dependency injection library (Spring, Castle, StructureMap, Ninject... etc.) ?***

We all use a DI container to abstract away a specific implementation of our code, but we could also use the same interface / strategy pattern to write a generic interface based DI container using specific implementations such as Castle.Windsor, Unity... etc.

In general the basic pattern of "Getting and Object" from a container is pretty universal. For example:

```
IService service = IocContainer.Get<IService>();
```

Where IocContainer is a generic wrapper  class around a specific library implementation such as Castle.Windsor, Unity... etc.

Of course in addition to writing specific implementations that you could 'plug-in' and of course, each implementation would have its own configuration file format.

Anyone have suggestions on existing well tested wrapper classes for DI containers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dependency Inject (DI) "friendly" library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045904/dependency-inject-di-friendly-library)

Comment: There's the [Common Service Locator](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com) project, but frankly, I agree with Remo Gloor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with all these wrappers and container abstractions is that they restrict you to the common subset of the functionallity that all the containers share. That's why you shouldn't do it. Instead use the container of your choice correctly:

1. Have just one "Get" in your application - in the composition root
2. Configure the container with conventions rather than usein a one by one service registration. This makes the configuration small.
3. Use factory interfaces wherever you have to create instances after the initial composition of your application and implement them as part of the container configuration (Some container do this implementation automatically for you)

With these simple rules your container is known in one place only - the composition root - which makes any abstraction of the container obsolete. That way you can use the full power of the container.

Comment: +1. Your code should be "DI agnostic" due to the fact that 99.99% of the code shouldn't ever reference the DI container or a wrapper. The question is asking about Service Location which is almost the complete opposite of what DI is supposed to be.