# Service Layer, Repository Layer and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, architecture, repository-pattern, separation-of-concerns, n-layer

I'm designing a layered architecture (all layers are on same machine) with using Entity Framework (POCO entities), to use same layers with an ASP.Net MVC application, mobile application, etc; also to maintain testability...

I will have UI Layer > Service Layer > Repository Layer > Entity Framework > Database, with Dependency Injection, layer abstraction, and separation of concerns.

- Assume that, I have two methods (Customer, Order are entity classes). Which layer I should place these methods?:

  - public IList GetOrdersByCustomerId(int CustomerId) that contains a LINQ query.
    *(Repository layer, or Service Layer?)*
  - public void RequestAnOrderAndStartTheShipmentProcess(Customer CustomerEntity, Order OrderEntity) that does some insert operations like orderRepository.Add(OrderEntity), shipmentRepository.Add(ShipmentEntity) etc...
    *(a separate Business Logic Layer, or Service Layer?)*
- I will have IOrderService interface, and "OrderService : IOrderService" class for dependency injection, will the interface and class be positioned in same assembly, or should be positioned in separate assemblies?

Thanks

### EDIT

Thanks for your answer. But in this case, four questions came to think about...
 1. If UI has a reference to DataAccess assembly, the developers can access to DataAccess classes directly in UI code, and shouldn't it create an extra effort to make code reviews (e.g. if there's a junior developer in team)?
 2. I understood that, I should have GetOrdersByCustomerId method both in Repository layer (doing the real querying) and Service Layer (calling GetOrdersByCustomerId method in OrderRepository class), is it correct?
 3. Also I should do CRUD operations for (nearly) all tables to maintain them, and think about I have 96 tables in my current project (it's not too much but it's not  few also), should I have Add, Update, Delete methods in Service layer too? Or should I think about more "behavioural" in my service layer?
 4. I confused about, if I have GetOrdersByCustomerById,
    GetOrdersByStatus, etc... methods in my OrderRepository, isn't it be
    like a DAO class?

Comment: In its original form, your question barely fitted the Q&A format of Stack Overflow (1 question that can be answered in a way that 1 answer can be accepted as the best one). After your edit even less so. You better ask a new well-scoped question. See the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: The difference between the Repository and a DAO class is that a Repository returns a populated business object whereas the DAO returns a DTO.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider an architecture, having three assemblies (layers):

**Business** 
Containng your service classes (and  also your RequestAnOrderAndStartTheShipmentProcess method). The business layer will contain all your core business rules, and therefore it is not very likely that you suddenly want to swap this layer out with a complete new one or add an alternative. Therefore I would keep both OrderService and IOrderService in this assembly. I would also put the POCO classes (have EF autogenerate these for you like [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/01/25/walkthrough-poco-template-for-the-entity-framework.aspx)) and repository interfaces in this layer.

**DataAccess** 
This is where you keep your EF repository implementations (and your GetOrdersByCustomerId method). This assembly references the business assembly, because it implements the repository interfaces found in that layer.

**UI** 
Here you instantiate the repositories from the DataAccess assembly and inject these into the service classes of the Business layer using constructor injection. Thus this assembly has references to Business and DataAccess.

Using this architecture your business layer is nicely seperated from the other layers and easy to unit test. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047657/1369673) answer for more details in dependency injection.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion (it's always a bit arbitrary):

1. Repository, because it is a typical specified get operation on a single entity set.
2. Service layer, because it orchestrates several operations on several entities.
3. Separate assemblies, so you can add interface implementations from other assemblies without having to reference an assembly that already contains an implementation.

Comment: Hmm, thanks... If RequestAnOrderAndStartTheShipmentProcess method belongs to Service Layer, is it correct to do all validations, complex business operations in Service Layer? What about Business Logic Layer, shouldn't I have any BLL? I'm confused about difference between Service Layer and Business Logic Layer...
And I'm thinking of KISS principle also :)

Comment: "Service" has many connotations. This is about domain services, which are nothing but a number of classes that coordinate several tasks that encompass domain entities. They are _part_ of the BLL in my view. BL vested in entities is another part. Validations (either validators or classes validating themselves) yet another part. I've loved to read Dino Esposito's Architecting Applications for the Enterprise. The whole area is a bit too wide to discuss here.