# Abstract the composition root in a reusable library

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, composition

In my first question

[Locate the correct composition root for a .NET library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681779/locate-the-correct-composition-root-for-a-net-library)

helped clarifying about Dependency Injection. The exhaustive answer of Steven states (*in few words if it possible*) that a reusable library is a particular a case and here we can use `poor-man-injection` (see the answer for completeness).

Studying the source code of [AutoFixture](https://github.com/AutoFixture), you can note that the main assembly use DI everywhere without depending on a container; something well explained in [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/) book.

The question is: **can someone introduce a pattern (or good practice) to to abstract the composition root without using a container?**

**Further notes (optional):**

Backing to AutoFixture where the composition root occurs in `Fixture` type constructors; I think that `*Relays` class are used to group instances in a similar manner some DI library has the concept of module.
It's interesting note that there's a type named `BehaviourRoot` that sits on the top of the graph (is this the kind of abstraction I'm searching?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [description of the Composition Root pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot) explicitly states that it can be implemented without a DI Container. The pattern is independent of container usage, and can be used with or without a container.

The Composition Root is the **entry point** of an application. By definition, it has **no callers** so it makes no sense to abstract it.

To quote the above article:

> The Composition Root is an *application infrastructure component*.
>
> Only applications should have Composition Roots. **Libraries and frameworks shouldn't**.

(bold my emphasis)

AutoFixture is a library, and thus has no Composition Root. The `Fixture` class is [Façade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), in the spirit of building a [DI-friendly library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047657/126014).

Comment: +1 and this answer. Don't know if a bit off-topic and maybe that continuing the read of the book, I could get the answer: but I try to ask. An example: I've a Façade like `Fixture` that supplies a service consuming types private to the reusable library. All types use DI through constructor injection. At some point (I presume in the Façade ctor) the graph should be created. If this is not the composition root, how to call it? And if this way of proceeding is correct, can you provide a comment about that? (e.g. a proper pattern to use or an indication...)

Comment: What about a plugin?  Could a plugin have a composition root?  The plugin has dependencies that it needs to manage also, independently of the application in which it is hosted.

Comment: A good plugin would follow the OCP, so while it might have dependencies, those dependencies might not have to be bundled in the plugin itself, but could be imported from yet other plugins. This is the reason that the Managed Extensibility Framework (as an example) explicitly models *imports* and *exports*. Thus, it would break the OCP if a plugin had its own Composition Root. If properly designed, all libraries are plugins, so the above answer still holds.

Comment: @MarkSeemann, thank you.  BTW - I really enjoy your book "Dependency Injection in .NET." I am using it as guidance currently.