# Dependency Injection (DI) internally in reusable class library

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, dependencies, ninject

I have a set of projects which provide all the functionality necessary to run a .Net service. The project makes use of Dependency Inject via Ninject.

My (simplified) solution looks like this:

```
Project 1: Windows Service (Composition Root)
^
Project 2: Server Engine & Heavy Lifting (Ninject Module)
^
Project 3: Persistence / DAL (Ninject Module)
^ 
Project 4: Interfaces & Basic / Shared functionality (Interfaces)
```

After some significant development, turns out I will need to create a new "client" library project used to communicate with the Windows Service. This client becomes a new project (`Project 5`) and depends on the functionality in `Project 3` and `Project 4`. I.e.:

```
Project 5: Client (Class Library)
^
Project 3: Persistence / DAL (Ninject Module)
^ 
Project 4: Interfaces & Basic / Shared functionality (Interfaces)
```

### 3 Immediate Problems:

1. I don't want to put the responsibility of wiring up an object graph on the consumer of the Client. The consumer should *just use it* like you have any other library you've used. You shouldn't have to worry about the internals of the library to make it work.
2. The Client is a class library and doesn't have an entry point of its own to consider my composition root and establish the object graph.
3. Even if I did have an entry point in the Client, my reading suggests I shouldn't have library dependencies on a DI framework *"In that case [of creating a reusable library] you should typically make your library working without a DI container. You should yourself not take a dependency on such a container, because this would drag the container in"* (from [Locate the correct composition root for a .NET library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681779/locate-the-correct-composition-root-for-a-net-library)). Another excerpt from a different post reads: *"Only applications should have Composition Roots. Libraries and frameworks shouldn't."* (from  http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

These problems root from the fact that I have already built much functionality into `Project 3` and `Project 4` that is mandatory to be used in the `Client`, yet these 2 projects already have a dependency on Ninject, so by proxy, the client also has a dependency on Ninject.

I can easily solve this problem using various methods, but I haven't found a resouding solution, they all feel "hacky", like I'm shoving a square peg in a round hole ([What are the best practices for class libraries using dependency injection for internal operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831455/what-are-the-best-practices-for-class-libraries-using-dependency-injection-for-i)).

Comment: Did you read this? http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/

Comment: Hi @Steven, I just gave it a read. While I understand the principals there, they are all centering around the concept of the application wiring up dependencies on behalf of (in my case) the `Client` and thus has too much of a heavy hand in using the `Client` IMO. My client is simple, it is not a massive framework, it should be easy to use with a few lines of code and should absolutely not require the consumer to wire up a graph.

Comment: @RyanGriffith That article suggests that the library can provide a Facade in order to make usage from a client as simple as possible. Using such a Facade could literally be a one-liner, depending on the preconditions of your library. Can it get any easier than that?

Comment: *"nor should I even be using DI within my library."* Where did you read that?

Comment: @MarkSeemann, thank you for the great posts, they're very helpful. I have corrected my question to correctly attribute that statement you mention. Regarding a Facade, would that become the composition root within the `Client` where we'd hookup our dependency graph? To reiterate, I'm bound to wiring up dependencies and using a specific DI framework because of my shared projects.

Comment: Regarding Facades, is there anything in [the article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library)'s example that's not sufficiently clear?

Comment: The example is clear and very informative, however, the advice is not when it comes to my problem. In your article(s), you take a general stance of the composition root being within the application and specifically outside of the actual library. I can solve all my problems by making my composition root inside of my facade in `Client`, but 1. Your example doesn't show this and 2. you appear to suggest against it.  You obviously have a lot of credibility, so I'm cautious to mix the two concepts when your posts appear to suggest against it. Please set me straight if I'm misinterpreting something.

Comment: How about using a DI container internally in your library but not exposing it to the outside world? Offer the facade to the outside world so a consumer of the library can easily use it, either by configuring his own DI container or not using a DI container at all.
You could also ILMerge the DI container into your assembly so the consumer of your library does not have to manage more dependencies.

Comment: Hi @MarkSeemann, just following up on this with my last comment. If you have a moment, I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @RyanGriffith It looks like you already found the answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1831481/126014