# dependency injection or factory pattern c#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have to write a Complex calculator logic which has 4 different components to be calculated brokerage, stockprice, admin charges & other charges. Each having a different logic and formulas.

So I decided to use Unity DI. I have a ContainerFactoryClass which resolves all classes which implements  IChargeCalculator interface as shown below in the TotalAnnualCostCalculator constructor.

```
public class TotalAnnualCostCalculator
{
    private readonly IUnityContainer container;

   //Constructor
    public TotalAnnualCostCalculator()
    {
        container = ContainerFactory.InitializeContainer();
        ContainerFactory.SetupContainer(container);
    }
    public AnnualCostCharges CalculateTotalAnnualCost(Parameters product)
    {
          var calculators = container.ResolveAll<ICalculator>().ToList();
          // Invoke calcualtion method

           Parallel.ForEach(calculators, c =>
        {
            return c.CalculateAnnualCost(product);

        });
    }

}
```

**Container Factory class:-**

```
public static class ContainerFactory
{
    public static IUnityContainer Container { get; private set; }
    public static IUnityContainer InitializeContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        RegisterDependencies(container);

        return container;
    }

    private static void RegisterDependencies(UnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<ICalculatorStrategyFactory, CalculatorStrategyFactory>("Factory");

        container.RegisterType<IEffectiveAnnualCostCalculator, InvestmentManagementChargeCalculator>("IMCChargeCalculator",
            new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ICalculatorStrategyFactory>("Factory")));
        //container.RegisterType<IEffectiveAnnualCostCalculator, AdministrationChargeCalculator>("AdministrationChargeCalculator");
        container.RegisterType<IEffectiveAnnualCostCalculator, AdviceChargeCalculator>("AdviceChargeCalculator");
        container.RegisterType<IEffectiveAnnualCostCalculator, OtherChargeCalculator>("OtherChargeCalculator");

        container.RegisterType<IInvestmentManagementChargeCalculator, LumpSumIMCCalculator>("LumpSumIMCCalculator");
        container.RegisterType<IInvestmentManagementChargeCalculator, DebitOrderIMCCalculator>("DebitOrderIMCCalculator");
    }

    public static void SetupContainer(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        Container = container;
    }
}
```

Then any API consumes my Calculator.dll by just creating an instance of TotalAnnualCostCalculator  and call a method like this.

```
var totalCharges = calc.CalculateTotalAnnualCost(prod);
```

**My code reviewer says its better to use Factory Pattern ,as this tightly coupled to Unity Framework.**

Please advise

Comment: first of all,            Parallel.ForEach(calculators, c =>
        {
            return c.CalculateAnnualCost(product);

        });
will only calculate one calculator (randomly depending on speed and position on the list) and return

Comment: If the goal is simply to de-couple from the DI framework then you can wrap all of the DI implementation in a simple custom container/interface that you control.  Treat it like any other dependency that you abstract behind an interface.  Basically write your own `IContainer` and public members of your initializer only accept/return that instead of `UnityContainer`.

Comment: Additionally, this may be more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps you should discuss this with your code reviewer. That said, consider using the Composite pattern instead of a Factory.

Comment: This question is really too broad. Suggest asking on CodeReview or SoftwareEngineering

Comment: Starting with 'So I decided to use Unity DI' is a smell.

Comment: If you have one IUnityContainer in ContainerFactory than you can resolve what ever you want from Container. This is service locator pattern and it is not good practice. Idea is to resolve only what you need in class, and container exist only on registration.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat: Good point. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, [don't use a DI Container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) at all. As Steven suggests in the comments, this seems a great fit for a [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern):

```
public class TotalAnnualCostCalculator : ICalculator
{
    private readonly ICalculator[] calculators;

    public TotalAnnualCostCalculator(params ICalculator[] calculators)
    {
        this.calculators = calculators;
    }

    public AnnualCostCharges CalculateTotalAnnualCost(Parameters product)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(this.calculators, c => c.CalculateAnnualCost(product));
    }
}
```

In the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot), then, you simply `new` up all the `ICalculator` objects you'd like to use, and pass them to the constructor of `TotalAnnualCostCalculator`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. But this would be standalone library and other API's refer to this .dll . So why does the external users need to know all the concrete classes.  Please can suggest for standalone library

Comment: @shashikumar If the external users don't need to know about the concrete classes in use, then why use DI at all? In general, however, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2047657/126014

Answer (score 0):

Register all IEffectiveAnnualCostCalculator (or what ever interface).
You just need to map the enumerable to an array of the same type.

```
container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IEffectiveAnnualCostCalculator>, IEffectiveAnnualCostCalculator[]>();
```

Resolve with dependency injection:

```
 private IEnumerable<IEffectiveAnnualCostCalculator> calculators;

 public TotalAnnualCostCalculator(IEnumerable<IEffectiveAnnualCostCalculator> calculators)
 {
     this.calculators = calculators;
 }

public AnnualCostCharges CalculateTotalAnnualCost(Parameters product)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(this.calculators, c => c.CalculateAnnualCost(product));
}
```